# Saving doc,xls,pdf,images into sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a application in which i want to store the word file,excel file,images,ppt etc into the database.But as i am new i don't know how can i store such kind of files.So please do help me

Database class

```
public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int dbVersion = 1;
    private static final String dbName = "HSsuraksha";
    private static final String tableName = "pocketDocs";
    private static final String userId = "userId";
    private static final String docId = "docId";
    private static final String fileName = "fileName";
    private static final String fileExt = "fileExt";
    private static final String title = "title";

    private static final String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(" + userId + " Integer Primary Key," + docId + " Integer," + fileName + " Text," + fileExt + " Text," + title + " Text" + ")";

    public DbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {

    }

    public void insertData(DbModel dbModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        database.beginTransaction();
        contentValues.put(userId, dbModel.userId);
        contentValues.put(docId, dbModel.docId);
        contentValues.put(fileName, dbModel.fileName);
        contentValues.put(fileExt, dbModel.fileExtension);
        contentValues.put(title, dbModel.title);
        if (contentValues != null) {
            Long id = database.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
            Log.e("insert values", "" + id);
        }

        database.endTransaction();

    }

    public DbModel selectDocs(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        DbModel model = new DbModel();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, new String[]{fileName, fileExt, title}, docId + "=?", new String[]{id}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            model.fileName = cursor.getString(2);
            model.fileExtension = cursor.getString(3);
            model.title = cursor.getString(4);
        }
        db.close();
        return model;
    }
}
```

DbModel

```
public class DbModel implements Serializable {
    public String userId, docId, fileName, fileExtension, title;

    public DbModel() {
    }

    public DbModel(String userId, String docId, String fileName, String fileExtension, String title) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.docId = docId;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getDocId() {
        return docId;
    }

    public void setDocId(String docId) {
        this.docId = docId;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileExtension() {
        return fileExtension;
    }

    public void setFileExtension(String fileExtension) {
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Class from where i am putting the data

```
dbHandler = new DbHandler(context);
        dbModel = new DbModel("1", "1", "GoogleDocs", ".pdf", "Test");
```

Comment: instead upload on ftp server

Comment: but sir as per my requirement i wanna store it in the database

Comment: what incase content is large in file ...db is not prefered then...its bad practice

Comment: Sir i have one more doubt can u help me out to solve it???

Comment: yup i can help u out btw i m girl not sir u can call me adcom, but ur issue need to be clear to me

Comment: Srry.I have created a model to store the data i.e DbModel.From other class i am putting the data in the the DbModel.But when i want that data in the select query i am getting it as null.y this so??.I am updating my post pls do have a look

Comment: ok tell me clearly u wanna store on metadata right yes or no? and from which storage u r getting these files?

Comment: @adcom i wanna insert dummy data into the database and use that data to display in the list

Comment: Alright , i m just concern about length of data how long will it be ...and i got the idea u wanna do now tell me did u created db structure? u r using local sqlite db or remote db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this lib for excel import and export , support upto `ms2007`

`http://poi.apache.org/download.html` , easily integrate it and for use

creating a excel-file , for other documents refer documents of poi lib.

```
// check if available and not read only 

   if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) { 
    Toast.makeText(context, "No External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only"); 
    return false; 
} 

boolean success = false; 

//New Workbook
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

Cell c = null;

//Cell style for header row
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

//New Sheet
Sheet sheet1 = null;
sheet1 = wb.createSheet("job");


Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);

c = row.createCell(0);
c.setCellValue("OperatorId : ");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row.createCell(1);
c.setCellValue("OperatorName : " );
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row.createCell(2);
c.setCellValue("Blade : " );
c.setCellStyle(cs);
c = row.createCell(3);
c.setCellValue("ShiftType : " );
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row.createCell(4);
c.setCellValue("Bom : ");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row.createCell(5);
c.setCellValue("Job Created at : ");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row.createCell(6);
c.setCellValue("Blade Number: " );
c.setCellStyle(cs);


sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));
sheet1.setColumnWidth(3, (15 * 500));
sheet1.setColumnWidth(4, (15 * 500));
sheet1.setColumnWidth(5, (15 * 500));
sheet1.setColumnWidth(6, (15 * 500));


Row row2 = sheet1.createRow(1);

c = row2.createCell(0);
c.setCellValue("JobId");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row2.createCell(1);
c.setCellValue("BladeName");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row2.createCell(2);
c.setCellValue("Start Time");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row2.createCell(3);
c.setCellValue("End Time");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row2.createCell(4);
c.setCellValue("Time Taken");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row2.createCell(5);
c.setCellValue("Ply Number");
c.setCellStyle(cs);




SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm_ddMMyyyy");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), historyID+"History_"+currentDateandTime+".xls"); 
FileOutputStream os = null; 

try { 
    os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(os);
    Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
    success = true; 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
} finally { 
    try { 
        if (null != os) 
            os.close(); 
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
    } 
} 

return success;
```

}

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() { 
String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) { 
    return true; 
} 
return false; 
} 

public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() { 
String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) { 
    return true; 
} 
return false; 
}
```

use permissions

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


// Reading a excel file

    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
    FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Create a POIFSFileSystem object 
    POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

    // Create a workbook using the File System 
    HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

    // Get the first sheet from workbook 
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

    /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
    Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
    Cell bladeIDcell = mySheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
    Cell bladeNameCell = mySheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);


    HSSFSheet mySheet2 = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(1);
        Iterator<Row> rowIter2 = mySheet2.rowIterator();

        while(rowIter2.hasNext()){
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter2.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            ArrayList<String> Valuesfromcell = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
                Valuesfromcell.add(myCell.toString());
                //Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: i dnt wanna create excel file i just wanna get the file from the the storage and store it in the Db

Comment: by using this lib you only read files , get the data from files and u can able to store that data in your database....